# using greek letters in tmap (in R)

Tags: r, tmap

I have been trying to include greek letters in my legend title when using functions in the `tmap` r-library. I have tried several different things, all resulting in mixed results, none of which produce a useable product. Attempts include:

1. The `Tex('$\\mu$')` function in the `latex2exp` r-library
2. `bquote(mu)`
3. finally olde but goodie `expression(paste(mu,"g",sep=""))`

All of these attempts either result in a line of text not including the greek letter or some variant with strange formatting.

Has anyone ran into this issue? If so could you please share your resources?

Edits/Additions:
Thanks to @James input unicode characters works perfectly in tmap. The next question is how to do superscript or subscripts without using the `expression` or `paste` functions since these functions are not 100% compatible with tmap.

Is there a way to have a superscript/subscript in a legend title for tmap? As you can tell units mean a lot to me (*wink).

Comment: Use the unicode character, `"\u03bc"`?

Comment: @James That did the trick!! Thanks for the pointer, I completely forgot about unicode characters. The next question is how to do superscript or subscript without the `paste` or `expression` functions in tmap.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured out the sub/superscript using unicode...(duh!) for superscript -1, `\u207B\u00B9` works. But if anyone has any other ideas feel free to pitch them.